# Function with arguments not working with window.onblur and onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onblur, onfocus

The following code isn't working

```
window.onfocus = welcome("John Doe");
window.onblur = bye("John Doe");

function welcome(name) {
    $("p").append("Welcome back " +name+ " <br>");
}

function bye(name) {
    $("p").append("Good bye " +name+ " see you soon <br>");
}
```

However I noticed that this code works for custom functions that dont take any argument. See code below. The following code is working:

```
window.onfocus = welcome; //No Argument here so this code works
window.onblur = bye; //Same here... No argument for the function

function welcome(name) {
    $("p").append("Welcome back John Doe <br>");
}

function bye(name) {
    $("p").append("Good bye John Doe see you soon <br>");
}
```

I am new to jquery and javascript and this stuff is confusing me. Can someone please explain why exactly it isn't working. and how can I make a custom function with arguments work with window.onfocus and onblur method. (reason for working or not working is more important for me as I want to understand the mechanics rather than cramming up the syntax)

Answer (score 1):

> `()(parenthesis)` after `function-name` will invoke/call the function by the time you are assigning the handler to the events.

Use `anonymous-function` instead of `invoking-function` and invoke/call the `function` inside it.

In your second(working) example, you are assigning function definition(body of the function) as a event-handler hence function is invoked after particular event.

```js
window.onfocus = function() {
  welcome("John Doe");
};
window.onblur = function() {
  bye("John Doe");
}

function welcome(name) {
  $("p").append("Welcome back " + name + " <br>");
}

function bye(name) {
  $("p").append("Good bye " + name + " see you soon <br>");
}
```

Comment: But why invoking-function isnt working ? why only anonymous-function is required

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(window).focus()` and `$(window).blur()` event:

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
        welcome("John Doe");
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        bye("John Doe");
    });
});

function welcome(name) {
    $("p").append("Welcome back John Doe <br>");
}

function bye(name) {
    $("p").append("Good bye John Doe see you soon <br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Add JavaScript file on page.

```js
window.onfocus = welcome("John Doe");
window.onblur = bye("John Doe");

function welcome(name) {
  $("p").append("Welcome back " + name + " <br>");
}

function bye(name) {
  $("p").append("Good bye " + name + " see you soon <br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p></p>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05c3qfzL/)

Comment: But not working as expected. (should execute on blur or focus).

Answer (score 0):

Both code is working fine for me. Try to put jQuery code in body section.

Comment: This should be a comment please